# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method. Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Url = "https://www.kap.org.tr/tr/Pazarlar"
R = requests.get(Url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(R.text,"lxml")
List = Soup.find("div", {"class": "w-col w-col-9 w-clearfix sub-col asd"}).find_all("div", {"class": "column-type7 wmargin"})

#print(List[0]) 

for stock_name in List[0]:
    #print(stock_name)
    stock_name.find("a", {"class": "vcell"})
```

I m trying to get stocks name all class one by one `(class="column-type7 wmargin")`. I can `print(List[0])` it's work but when i tried to get just stocks name `"a", {"class": "vcell"}` in for loop i encountered this error TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method. How can i get just stocks name? I'll appreciate for all helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get directly from `Soup` or your `List[0]`.Python has `find` method for strings and `bs4` has find method. your for loop will give you an error `TypeError: find() takes no keyword`.

```
name=Soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class":"comp-cell _03 vtable"})
names=[i.a.get_text() for i in name]
names
```

Output:

```
['AG ANADOLU GRUBU HOLDİNG A.Ş.',
 'AKBANK T.A.Ş.',
 'AKÇANSA ÇİMENTO SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.',
 'AKFEN GAYRİMENKUL YATIRIM ORTAKLIĞI A.Ş.',.......]
```

or you can find the all `a` tags directly

```
name=List[0].find_all('a',attrs={"class":"vcell"})
names=[i.get_text() for i in name]
```

Output:

```
['1',
 'AGHOL',
 'AG ANADOLU GRUBU HOLDİNG A.Ş.',
 '2',
 'AKBNK',
 'AKBANK T.A.Ş.',
 '3',
 'AKCNS',
 'AKÇANSA ÇİMENTO SANAYİ VE TİCARET A.Ş.',.....]
```

Comment: `names[1::3]` you can use list slicing

Comment: where `names[start:end:step]`